# MongoDB's $graphLookup. Dealing with nodes that have multiple parents and multiple children

Tags: mongodb, graph

I'm trying to work with the new MongoDB v3.4 $graphLookup aggregation pipeline element. I have data "nodes" that can have 0, 1, or multiple parent nodes. Each node can also have 0, 1, or multiple child nodes. I'd like to use $graphLookup to produce the following output:

```
 {"parentNodeKey":  undefined, "parentLabel": undefined, "nodeKey": 1, "nodeLabel": "Node 1"},
 {"parentNodeKey":  1, "parentLabel": "Node 1", "nodeKey": 11, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.1"},
 {"parentNodeKey":  1, "parentLabel": "Node 1", "nodeKey": 12, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.2"},
 {"parentNodeKey":  1, "parentLabel": "Node 1", "nodeKey": 13, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.3"},
 {"parentNodeKey":  1, "parentLabel": "Node 1", "nodeKey": 31, "nodeLabel": "Node 3.1"},
 {"parentNodeKey": 11, "parentLabel": "Node 1.1", "nodeKey": 111, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.1.1"},
 {"parentNodeKey": 11, "parentLabel": "Node 1.1", "nodeKey": 112, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.1.2"},
 {"parentNodeKey": 12, "parentLabel": "Node 1.2", "nodeKey": 121, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.2.1"},
 {"parentNodeKey": 12, "parentLabel": "Node 1.2", "nodeKey": 122, "nodeLabel": "Node 1.2.2"}
```

The data is stored in the following schema (I can change this if necessary):

```
{"_id":   1, "nodeKey":  1, "label": "Node 1", "children": [{"nodeKey": 11, "label": "Node 1.1"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 12, "label": "Node 1.2"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 13, "label": "Node 1.3"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 31, "label": "Node 3.1"}
                                                        ]},
{"_id":   2, "nodeKey":  2, "label": "Node 2", "children": [{"nodeKey": 21, "label": "Node 2.1"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 22, "label": "Node 2.2"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 23, "label": "Node 2.3"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 12, "label": "Node 1.2"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 31, "label": "Node 3.1"}
                                                        ]},
{"_id":   3, "nodeKey":  3, "label": "Node 3", "children": [{"nodeKey": 31, "label": "Node 3.1"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 32, "label": "Node 3.2"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 33, "label": "Node 3.3"}
                                                        ,{"nodeKey": 11, "label": "Node 1.1"}
                                                        ]},
{"_id":  11, "nodeKey": 11, "label": "Node 1.1", "children": [{"nodeKey": 111, "label": "Node 1.1.1"}
                                                          ,{"nodeKey": 112, "label": "Node 1.1.2"}
                                                          ]
                                            , "parents": [{"nodeKey": 1, "label": "Node 1"}
                                                         ,{"nodeKey": 3, "label": "Node 3"}
                                                         ]},
{"_id":  12, "nodeKey": 12, "label": "Node 1.2", "children": [{"nodeKey": 121, "label": "Node 1.2.1"}
                                                          ,{"nodeKey": 122, "label": "Node 1.2.2"}
                                                          ]
                                            , "parents": [{"nodeKey": 1, "label": "Node 1"}
                                                         ,{"nodeKey": 2, "label": "Node 2"}
                                                         ]},
{"_id":  13, "nodeKey": 13, "label": "Node 1.3", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 1, "label": "Node 1"}]},
{"_id":  21, "nodeKey": 21, "label": "Node 2.1", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 2, "label": "Node 2"}]},
{"_id":  22, "nodeKey": 22, "label": "Node 2.2", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 2, "label": "Node 2"}]},
{"_id":  23, "nodeKey": 23, "label": "Node 2.3", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 2, "label": "Node 2"}]},
{"_id":  31, "nodeKey": 31, "label": "Node 3.1", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 1, "label": "Node 1"}
                                                         ,{"nodeKey": 2, "label": "Node 2"}
                                                         ,{"nodeKey": 3, "label": "Node 3"}]},
{"_id":  32, "nodeKey":  32, "label": "Node 3.2", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 3, "label": "Node 3"}]},
{"_id":  33, "nodeKey":  33, "label": "Node 3.3", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 3, "label": "Node 3"}]},
{"_id": 111, "nodeKey": 111, "label": "Node 1.1.1", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 11, "label": "Node 1.1"}]},
{"_id": 112, "nodeKey": 112, "label": "Node 1.1.2", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 11, "label": "Node 1.1"}]},
{"_id": 121, "nodeKey": 121, "label": "Node 1.2.1", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 12, "label": "Node 1.2"}]},
{"_id": 122, "nodeKey": 122, "label": "Node 1.2.2", "parents": [{"nodeKey": 12, "label": "Node 1.2"}]}
```

It appears that $graphLookup doesn't provide any information about a node's immediate parent node. I've used the following aggregation pipeline, unsuccessfully:

```
db.nodes.aggregate(
[{$match: {"nodeKey": 1}
 }
,{$graphLookup : {
    from            : "nodes",
    startWith       : "$children.nodeKey",
    connectFromField: "children.nodeKey",
    connectToField  : "nodeKey",
    maxDepth        : 5,
    depthField      : "depth",
    as              : "child"}
 }
,{
     $project: {
          "_id"           : 0
         ,"nodeKey"       : 1
         ,"child.depth"   : 1
         ,"child.nodeKey" : 1
         ,"child.label"   : 1
     }
  }
]).pretty()
```

I'm looking for any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to change collection document structure to reference `nodekey's` in `children` and `parents` array.

Something like this

```
{"_id":  12, "nodeKey": 12, "label": "Node 1.2", "children": [121, 122], "parents": [1, 2]}
```

Use the below aggregation query.

This should help you get going. I'll let you work with it to get to your desired output.

The important point to note we've to use `$graphLookup` couple of times. First lookup will get you `childs` and next will get you `parents` for childs.

```
db.nodes.aggregate([
     {$match: {"nodeKey": 1}},
     {$graphLookup : {
        from            : "nodes",
        startWith       : "$children",
        connectFromField: "children",
        connectToField  : "nodeKey",
        maxDepth        : 5,
        as              : "child"}
     },
     {$unwind:"$child"},
     {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$child"}},
     {$graphLookup : {
        from            : "nodes",
        startWith       : "$parents",
        connectFromField: "parents",
        connectToField  : "nodeKey",
        maxDepth        : 5,
        as              : "parent"
        }
     },
     {$project: {
         _id           : 0,
         parentNodeKey : "$parent.nodeKey",
         parentLabel   : "$parent.label",
         nodeLabel     : "$label",
         nodeKey       : 1
         }
     }
]);
```

Output after first lookup

```
{ "_id" : 121, "nodeKey" : 121, "label" : "Node 1.2.1", "parents" : [ 12 ] }
{ "_id" : 112, "nodeKey" : 112, "label" : "Node 1.1.2", "parents" : [ 11 ] }
{ "_id" : 122, "nodeKey" : 122, "label" : "Node 1.2.2", "parents" : [ 12 ] }
{ "_id" : 31, "nodeKey" : 31, "label" : "Node 3.1", "parents" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 12, "nodeKey" : 12, "label" : "Node 1.2", "children" : [ 121, 122 ], "parents" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : 111, "nodeKey" : 111, "label" : "Node 1.1.1", "parents" : [ 11 ] }
{ "_id" : 13, "nodeKey" : 13, "label" : "Node 1.3", "parents" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : 11, "nodeKey" : 11, "label" : "Node 1.1", "children" : [ 111, 112 ], "parents" : [ 1, 3 ] }
```

Final Output

```
{ "nodeKey" : 121, "parentNodeKey" : [ 1, 2, 12 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 1", "Node 2", "Node 1.2" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.2.1" }
{ "nodeKey" : 112, "parentNodeKey" : [ 1, 3, 11 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 1", "Node 3", "Node 1.1" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.1.2" }
{ "nodeKey" : 122, "parentNodeKey" : [ 1, 2, 12 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 1", "Node 2", "Node 1.2" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.2.2" }
{ "nodeKey" : 31, "parentNodeKey" : [ 3, 2, 1 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 3", "Node 2", "Node 1" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 3.1" }
{ "nodeKey" : 12, "parentNodeKey" : [ 2, 1 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 2", "Node 1" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.2" }
{ "nodeKey" : 111, "parentNodeKey" : [ 1, 3, 11 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 1", "Node 3", "Node 1.1" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.1.1" }
{ "nodeKey" : 13, "parentNodeKey" : [ 1 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 1" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.3" }
{ "nodeKey" : 11, "parentNodeKey" : [ 3, 1 ], "parentLabel" : [ "Node 3", "Node 1" ], "nodeLabel" : "Node 1.1" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Veeram. I hadn't thought to use $graphLookup more than once in the same aggregation; it's obvious now that you've mentioned it :-) You've given me something to think about and experiment with. I'll post my results when I finish my investigation.